# ListView with endless scroll: how to prevent refreshing visible rows?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, custom-adapter

I've implemented `OnScrollListener` to understand if the user is at the end of the list and I've managed to successfully appended new data to my list as follows:

```
@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

    if (scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
        if (list.getLastVisiblePosition() >= list.getCount()-1) {
            currentPage++;
            loadMore(currentPage);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is `notifyDataSetChanged` refreshes the whole ListView as expected. But since in my list there are images that are asynchronously loaded from the internet, this refresh causes the images to load again and this is obviously not desired. The applications like Facebook, Twitter etc they seamlessly attach new data at the end without this kind of refreshing at all. How do they do it, how can I also achieve this seamless endless scroll?

I think I have to do something in my adapter's `getView` method to prevent reload but I could not figure it out yet. Is there a known way for it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to want to implement an image cache. The cache should be asked for the images and either load them asynchronously from the internet or load them from memory if used before. The cache should be used in `getView`.

The simplest way to do a cache is to have a hashmap (probably a ConcurrentHashMap if you are getting the images async on a separate thread), where the keys are the url and the value is the image you want to show. You can then check if the hashmap has the value first, otherwise get the image and insert in the hashmap as well. There are many other ways to do this if you look around, but this is probably the easiest.

This solution is more robust, as you do not need to worry about what to invalidate and you do not need to worry about making more than one call when requesting the same image.

Comment: cache would help that re-downloading images yes, but I cannot avoid refreshing the preexisting rows then, can I?

Comment: @ecem I'm not sure why you are so hung up on the other rows being refreshed, the notifyDataSetChanged method is the proper way to handle this. The rows are redrawn all the time and worrying about them is premature optimization, especially if you use the convertView parameter in the getView method properly. The real delay that users will notice is in the network delay for getting the images. If you really want to test this, just point all the images to a static bitmap and tell me if you notice any delay when using notifyDataSetChanged.

Comment: okay I've tried your suggestion about static images and you are absolutely right, the change is not noticeable at all. Then caching it is! Thank you!